# mismatch exception handling

Tags: java, error-handling

```
 do{
        System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 and 1024 :"); //asking user to enter a number between 1 and 1024
        try{
            num=sc.nextInt();
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException e){
            System.out.println("Not an integer!");
        }
    }while(num<0 || num>1024);
```

> Basically I'm testing a working program and i was trying to fix it so
>   if the user enters, for example 'a', instead of an integer - the
>   program won't crash. however, this resulted in an infinite loop and
>   doesn't really work. any ideas why?

Comment: add `sc.next();` in the catch block.

Comment: Thanks ! works great  now